# Merge object arrays with matched secondary object nested inside root of the primary object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two object arrays that i need to match based on a key [ContactID].  I'd like to add the matched secondary object (if there is one) as a nested document rather than into the root of the primary object.  This is what my current solution does.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  thanks

```
let primaryData = [{ ContactID: 'abc-def', Name: 'Test'}, { ContactID: 'ghi-jkl', Name: 'Test 2'}]
let secondaryData = [{ _id: '1', name: 'Test', ContactID: 'abc-def'}]

let final = primaryData.map(function(item){
  return Object.assign(item, secondaryData.find(({ContactID}) => ContactID == item.ContactID));
});
```

Current Output

```
[{
    ContactID: "abc-def" ,
    Name: "Test" ,
    _id: "1" ,
    name: "Test"
},
{
    ContactID: "ghi-jkl" ,
    Name: "Test 2"
}]
```

Desired Output

```
[{
    ContactID: "abc-def" ,
    Name: "Test" ,
    secondaryData: {
        _id: "1" ,
        name: "Test",
        ContactID: "abc-def"
    }
},
{
    ContactID: "ghi-jkl" ,
    Name: "Test 2"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object.assign won't add properties to your field it just merges the two objects. You can add the secondaryData key for when it exists like so
`item['secondaryData'] = ...`

```
let primaryData = [{ ContactID: 'abc-def', Name: 'Test'}, { ContactID: 'ghi-jkl', Name: 'Test 2'}]
let secondaryData = [{ _id: '1', name: 'Test', ContactID: 'abc-def'}]
let final2 = primaryData.map(function(item){
     const secondaryFind = secondaryData.find(({ContactID}) => ContactID == item.ContactID);
     //If item exists in secondaryData add it to secondat=ryItem to current item
     secondaryFind && (item['secondaryData'] = secondaryFind);
     return item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let primaryData = [{
  ContactID: 'abc-def',
  Name: 'Test'
}, {
  ContactID: 'ghi-jkl',
  Name: 'Test 2'
}]
let secondaryData = [{
  _id: '1',
  name: 'Test',
  ContactID: 'abc-def'
}]

console.log(primaryData.map(function(item) {
 
  var second = secondaryData.filter(s => s.ContactID === item.ContactID);
  if (second.length)
    item.secondaryData = second;
  return item;
}));
```